# C++ STL - why use !(w < *i) rather than (w==*i)

Tags: c++, stl

```
vector<Widget> vw;
// populate vw
sort(vw.begin(), vw.end());
Widget w;

vector<Widget>::iterator i = lower_bound(vw.begin(), vw.end(), w);

if ( (i != vw.end()) && !(w < *i) ) // Yes, it is correct!
    // found w in vw
```

Here is my understanding:

The return value of ***i** from lower_bound is always NOT less than that of **w**.
In other words, `w <= *i`

Here is the question, why not directly use the following condition for checking?

```
if ( (i != vw.end()) && (w == *i) ) // why not use (w == *i)?
    // found w in vw
```

thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because the implicit interface `<algorithm>` uses for sorting and that kind of stuff only requires the `<` operator to be defined on the data type. If they used `==`, they would force developers to implement it too on custom types to benefit from these functions.

In other words, if you make a sortable type `Foo`, to use the functions defined in `<algorithm>`, you only need to overload the `<` operator.

Comment: do you mean the Widget only needs to overload operator< rather than operator==? -- thank you

Comment: @q0987 Yes, that's what I mean.